# RegExReplace everything after .com

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I'm trying to essentially take everything in the URL and replace what comes after the .com

Here is what I have so far:

```
clipboard := RegExReplace(clipboard, "/\.com(.*$)/", "")
```

I'm rather new with RegEx so anything helpful would be great!

This seems to work for now:

```
clipboard := RegExReplace(clipboard, "\.com(.*)", ".com")
```

Comment: What's wrong with your regex?

Comment: Good Question - I'm not sure :@

Comment: Your new regex will break URLs like `http://www.computer.com`.

Comment: It would be good to note that Autohotkey uses PCRE for its regex engine. That means it differs in some respects to the engine used in dotnet.

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with AutoHotKey, but I believe that right now you are replacing your entire string with an empty one. Try this instead:

```
clipboard := RegExReplace(clipboard, "/(.*\.com)(?:$|[/?].*$)/", "$1")
```

It captures everything up to and including the `.com` and keeps only that. It also makes sure the .com is the right one and not

> www. **com** puter.com

or

> wwww.website.com?redirect=google **.com**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    com                      'com'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [/?]                    any character of: '/', '?'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
```

Answer (score 0):

`clipboard := RegExReplace(clipboard, "\.com\b\K.*")`